# Live Sass Compiler still complaining about error I already fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Ayo can someone please help me.

So basically I'm just messing around with react here making a todolist as a frontendmentor challenge. I'm using sass for my styles. Everything seemed to be ok until yesterday.

When I hit save on the style.scss file the compiler goes:

```
Compilation Error
Error: File "/home/alwin/Documents/dev-shit/frontendmentor-todo-app/src/styles/.checkBox" not found
        on line 1 of home/alwin/Documents/dev-shit/frontendmentor-todo-app/src/styles/_addTodo.scss
        from line 4 of sass/home/alwin/Documents/dev-shit/frontendmentor-todo-app/src/styles/style.scss
>> @import "./.checkBox";

   --------^
```

But I don't think this error is relevant anymore, since I deleted the import of the checkbox stylesheet.

Here's my style.scss:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap");

@import "./variables";
@import "./addTodo";
@import "./todoHeader";

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("../images/bg-desktop-dark.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-color: hsl(235, 21%, 11%);
  color: white;
}

.todoContainer {
  // background: #19dafa;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 35%;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .todoContainer {
    min-width: 260px;
    min-height: 500px;
  }
}
```

I already reinstalled live sass compiler extension several times, so I don't know how to solve this.

I know I sound stupid, but am I missing something? Answers or corrections would be pretty much appreciated. Thanks in advance.